# How to manage FTP file sync in websites?

Tags: web, ftp

I just set up a personal website. I'm an iOS developer and am not well versed with the web development procedure. I'm using Transmit as an FTP client to manage my website, and I just noticed the sync feature. Now, how do I make it so that I can make changes and but not delete the new data that is on my FTP server ? Everytime I make a change in my local version of the website on my laptop, won't it delete some files on the FTP ?